# Matlab: How to avoid italic font for plot labels when interpreter is latex?

Tags: matlab, plot, latex

let's say that one plots something and either for title or legend or labels uses interpreter as latex, by default the title or ... will be shown in *italic*, how can one suppress that?

for instance for y-axis label it is as below:

```
ylabel('$\frac{P_{shape}}{P_{circle}}$','FontSize', 28,'Interpreter','LaTex')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is actually related to Latex and not related to MATLAB!

`\mathrm` is used for that purpose in Latex.
Anyway, the following will achieve your desired result:

```
ylabel('$\mathrm{\frac{P_{shape}}{P_{circle}}}$','FontSize', 28,'Interpreter','LaTex')
```